# When do I need to include LayoutCS in Chapel sparse matrices?

Tags: sparse-matrix, chapel

I have not been able to isolate, but sometimes I get an error for not including

```
use LayoutCS;
```

When I

```
use LinearAlgebra.Sparse;
```

in Chapel.  When do I need to include it and what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When do I need to include it?

[`LayoutCS`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/layouts/LayoutCS.html) is necessary if you are explicitly constructing a compressed sparse sparse domain using the `dmapped` clause:

```
var spsD: sparse subdomain(D) dmapped CS();
```

[`LinearAlgebra.Sparse`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra/Sparse.html) is necessary if you are using the higher level linear algebra interface to accomplish the same thing:

```
var spsD = csrDomain(D);
```

> What other options do I have?

As of Chapel 1.16, `LinearAlgebra.Sparse` only supports `CSR` arrays, so using `LayoutCS` would enable you to also use `CSC` arrays if you needed them:

```
var spsD: sparse subdomain(D) dmapped CS(compressRows=false);
```

You can also use the default sparse format of `COO` without using any modules:

```
var spsD: sparse subdomain(D);
```

See the [sparse primer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/sparse.html) for more examples.